# How to create an object of a class at runtime C#

Tags: c#, class, constructor, runtime

For example, I want to create a program that records the book title, author, genre, etc., each book is a separate class object, how can I make it so that I can automatically declare new class objects during the program's operation (I need this for educational purposes)

Comment: You can use anonymous types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Activator.CreateInstance` method to create a new instance of a given type. This example demonstrates the usage.

```cs
class MyType
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "My type.";
    }
}

MyType obj = Activator.CreateInstance<MyType>();
Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

If you have a type that has constructor parameters, these can be given in the following way:

```cs
class MyTypeWithConstructor
{
    string _message;

    public MyTypeWithConstructor(string message)
    {
        _message = message;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _message;
    }
}

object[] parameters = new object[1] { "Hello world!" };
MyTypeWithConstructor obj2 = (MyTypeWithConstructor)Activator.CreateInstance(
    typeof(MyTypeWithConstructor), args: parameters);

Console.WriteLine(obj2);
```